# Сравнение дат в datetime

Tags: python, datetime

Скажите, почему при сравнении дат в библиотеке datetime выводит неверный результат?

```
import datetime as dt

d = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

ddate = dt.date(3000, 7, 5)
dd = ddate.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

print(d)
print(dd)
print(dd > d)
```

Разве 3000 год не больше, чем 2020 год?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы переводите формат `datetime.datetime` и `datetime.date` в строки (именно это делает метод `strftime`), и потом их сравниваете. Разумеется, строка `09.11.2020` больше строки `05.07.3000`.

Сравнивать нужно непосредственно данные в форматах datetime:

```
dt.datetime.now() < dt.datetime(3000, 7, 5)
# True
```

**UPDATE**

Если вам изначально дана строка, то переведите ее в формат dateimte и сравнивайте:

```
import datetime as dt
my_string = "07.02.3000"
my_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(my_string, '%d.%m.%Y')

print(my_dt > dt.datetime.now())
# True
```

Comment: просто мне дана строка даты с типом str: `'07.07.2000'` и хочу сравнить эту str с сегодняшней датой. Как из str можно преобразовать, чтобы правильно сравнить даты?

Comment: я обновил ответ.